# Is it Opscenter configurable with Scylla?

Tags: cassandra, scylla

For Scylla monitoring, we need to configure Grafana but is it possible to integrate Cassandra Opscenter to Scylla?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR: No.
OpsCenter is a closed source product, which was not tested with Scylla. Part of it that uses Apache Cassandra CQL and JMX will probably work, while others might not.
In addition to the open source, Scylla monitoring stack (base on Prometheus and Grafana), ScyllaDB has its own close version product for cluster management named Scylla Manager.

Tzach (Scylla Product Manager)

Comment: Further, Scylla's Monitoring stack (https://docs.scylladb.com/operating-scylla/monitoring/monitoring_stack/) is free and open source. Scylla Manager (https://docs.scylladb.com/operating-scylla/manager/) is free for up to 5 node clusters. Requires a Scylla Enterprise license for larger clusters. 
Full disclosure - both Tzach and I work on Scylla.